# How to interpret sin(x) with eval() in python

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to allow the user to type `sin(x) - y` to set up an equation using SymPy, however, with my current code, when you input this, it returns:

> TypeError: can't convert expression to float

My current code is:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import math
from math import sin, cos, tan

x, y = sp.symbols('x y')
literalEq = input("Enter equation")
eq = eval(literalEq)
```

I am quite new to using SymPy, could you please help me out?

Comment: What do you use as `input` for this code? For me an input like this works just fine: `sin(2)-3` returning `-2.090702573174318`

Comment: the `math.sin` requires a numeric argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to put directly `x` and `y` in the input which are mainly counted as expressions instead of anything else. You need to put the direct values like `sin(3) - 5` which will return `-4.858879991940133`.

Or you can use `sympify` function to make the equation sympified to work on it using `evalf` function.

```
import sympy
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_unicode=True)

x, y = sympy.symbols('x y')
literalEq = str(input("Enter equation "))
literalEq = sympify(literalEq)
literalEq = literalEq.evalf()
pprint(literalEq) #For pretty printing
```

Or importing `sin` *(and/or your required trigonometric functions)* from sympy also works.

```
import sympy
from sympy import * #or from sympy import sin
init_printing(use_unicode=True)

x, y = sympy.symbols('x y')
literalEq = input("Enter equation ")
eq = eval(literalEq)
pprint(eq)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to take x as an input, sorry I should've been more clear. And both the solutions work, once again, thanks!